# Regex to find multiple matched items at one time

Tags: c#, regex, match, regex-group

So here is the string:
"DC:PPE Env:CH1 Slice:whatever  to extract"
or "babaasdfsd DC:PPE asdfas  Env:CH1  or Slice:whatever "

basically I am trying to find "DC:PPE" "Env:CH1" "Slice:whatever" and remove them.

I am using the following regex:(c#)

```
Regex r = new Regex(
    @"(?:
    (?<captured>(?:^|\s+)Slice|Env|Dc:.*?\s+)()
  ){1}
  \1",
```

with `(?:^|\s+)` I am trying to match either Slice|Env|Dc appear at the beginning or have leading spaces with it.
 With `.*?\s+` I am trying to non-greedy match the spaces after DC:PPE.

I want it to return all three matches together.
What is wrong with this?

```
string combinedTestSTring = "DC:PPE Env:CH1 Slice:whatever  to extract";

Regex r = new Regex(
    @"(?:
    (?<captured>(?:^|\s+)Slice|Env|Dc:.*?\s+)()
  ){1}
  \1",

RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace|RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);


var a = r.Matches(combinedTestSTring);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\b(:?Slice|Env|Dc):.+?)\b");
```

`\b` matches a word boundary. Then it matches `Slice|Env|Dc` followed by `:` and then at least one character leading up to another word boundary.

You can't return all matches together.  When returning an array of matches, each element corresponds to a different capturing group in the regexp.  If you have a group with a repeat count or wildcard, the returned match is just the last one found, not all of them. So you have to write a loop that walks through the input string, returning each match.

However, if you just want replace them all, `r.Replace()` will do that, since it replaces all the matches in the string.

Comment: The best I can get right now is:
   string combinedTestSTring = "DC:PPE Env:CH1 Slice:whatever  to extract";

            Regex r = new Regex(
        @"(?:
        (?<captured>(?:\s+|^)(?:DC|Slice|Env):.*?\s+)()
      ){1}
      \1",

   foreach (Match m in r.Matches(combinedTestSTring))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", m.Groups["captured"]);
            }
but this only print out Slice:whatever and DC:ppe, but not Env:CH1...

Comment: The problem is that the \s+ at the end of the first match eats up all the whitespace, so there's no whitespace to match at the beginning of the second one. That's why you should use \b instead of \s+.